# Iterating through the elements of a HashSet containing user defined objects and displaying the elements that meet a certain criteria

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, iteration, java-stream

```
public class AnotherCompany {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Employee> h = new HashSet<Employee>();
        Employee e0 = new Employee("Mayank","IT",50000,10,10,10);
        Employee e1 = new Employee("Dhruv","IT",50000,10,10,10);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("Mayank","Accounts",50000,10,10,10);
        Employee e3 = new Employee("Mayank","IT",50000,10,10,10);
        h.add(e0);
        h.add(e1);
        h.add(e2);
        h.add(e3);
        e0.display(h,"IT");
    }
}
```

Now if I have to write a display method which displays only those employees that work in the IT department,What do I do?

Comment: are you using java 8?

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: yes i'm using java 8

Comment: Have a look at [foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/118/basic-control-structures/471/for-each#t=201610281130213972344).

Comment: Yes its my homework!

Comment: You need to read about "for" and "if" if you want to learn how to do this exercise.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple `for-loop` iteration to get the results. Let's assume `Employee` has `private String field`.

```
Set<Employee> newSet = new HashSet<>();

for (Employee e: h) {
    if (e.getField().equals("IT")) {
        newSet.add(e);
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

You can achieve the same result using `Stream API` from `Java 8` (see [these](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) [articles](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2-2227132.html) about it):

```
Set<Employee> newSet = h.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.field.equals("IT"))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

You may want to print them out instead of adding all of them in a new `Set`:

```
h.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.field.equals("IT"))
    .forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + "\n"));
```

---

There's also the better way of declaration:

```
Set<Employee> h = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: even if Employee has a private String field it can still be accessed by a member method in the same class!

Comment: can you tell me more about the getField() method?

Comment: Argh you were faster with the stream answer :-) + 1 for proper Java 8

Comment: @MayankBhardwaj I have forgotten that there is no need to use a getter in the stream. I fixed if. It was meant to be a getter.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis As I said `HashSet` is now the default implementation for `Collectors::toSet` but this might change in future Java releases. To make sure you'll get a `HashSet` you should use `Collectors::toCollection`.

Comment: Isn't OP asking about how to print things, rather than how to create new filtered set? Why do you have newSet in first example?

Comment: @Artur Biesiadowsi Already fixed. However it depends on OP's preferencies since he has lot's of answers here.

Comment: You can avoid the print with + "\n" with forEach(System.out::println)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void display(HashSet<Employee> h,String dept) {
    for(Employee e : h) {
        if(e.dept.equals(dept)) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `HashSet<Employee> h = new HashSet<Employee>();`
   use something like 
    `Set<Employee> h = new HashSet<>();`
2. Inside `display` method use

   ```
   for (Employee  emp : h) {
     if(emp.getDepartment().equals(department)) {
       System.out.println("Employee found");
     }
   }
   ```

Note: With jdk 8, you can try to use functional style loop.